# Is entertainment for its own sake permissible?

Tags: performance-entertainment, art

Are there sources that deal with the legitimacy of fictional writing (or other arts) as to whether it has a legitimate function such as tikkun olam or would it fall under some other category? Or is it wasteful pursuit? What makes it permissible or not permissible?